# How to find outlier data points on a log-gamma distribution?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, outliers, gamma-distribution, scipy

I’m dealing with a correlation network (only positive values) with `M` nodes where I’ve grouped features by `N` categories and summed up their connections. I now have a (`N x N`) matrix of connectivity values (sums of positive correlations). I’ve taken the upper triangle and got the non-zero values and log-transformed them to get the distribution in the figure.

I want to plot my network but I can’t plot (N**2 - N)/2 edges because it will just be a hairball network and I won't be able to get any useful information from it. In other words, I want to plot only the highest weighted edges but I do not want to make the threshold arbitrary. I thought that fitting my distribution to an appropriate distribution would be the first step.

I've been going through different distributions and found one that the [log-gamma distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.loggamma.html) described my data pretty well.

This might be a very naive question but now that I can confidently model my data, how can I determine values that are *statistically high on this distribution*? I get that "statistically high" is probably raising a million red flags but please bear with me.  I would like to find points that are unusually high given random chance for the distribution.

For example, in a normal distribution if there are points with a z-score of 3.

**What methods do I have with a log-gamma distribution to determine outlier points?**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by “statistically high” and “statistically significant”? For the latter, it does not appear that statistical significance should come up here, so I have to wonder if you’re using that term in a nonstandard way.

Comment: I most likely am misusing the term.  In particular, I was referring to statistical significance in the context of outliers.  For example, a high zscore of a point in a normal distribution.  Is there an equivalent for a log-gamma?

Comment: Consider what it means to be $3\sigma$ from the mean of a normal distribution. (I dislike where I’m going with this for outlier detection, and I don’t even like the idea of considering points outliers just because they’re unusual, but I do have a plan for now.)

Comment: I'm trying applied statistics instead of saying "here's the top 100".  I can't use all of the points in a figure so I need be able to say "I'm choosing these because of x, y, and z".  Can you guide me through the application of this? I thought fitting to a distribution would be the first step in this.

Comment: I don’t follow what you’re trying to do, why you can’t display all of your data in a plot, which points you’re choosing to plot, or what the “top 100” points are. Please explain. It sounds like you might have an XY problem where you want to solve X and see Y as a possible solution, so you’re asking about Y when what you really want to solve is X. What is your X?

Comment: This is a distribution of 68265 edge weights in a network.  If I plot all of the edges, it will be a giant "hairball" plot that isn't informative.  I want to plot the highest weighted edges and to use some statistical measure to determine a cutoff.

Comment: @O.rka, based on the choose distribution you can define a quantile function. For the case of a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ what you describe as being $3\sigma$ away, because a Gaussian is symmetric, essentially says, "*if something is above the 99.87th percentile or below the 0.13th percentile, we will call it an outlier*" the same can be done with that log-Gamma. :) (Or any other distribution you can have an empirical CDF for that matter).

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you, this is very helpful.  How would I be able to calculate this from the CDF? Here is the API if it's useful https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.loggamma.html Which parameters can I use? Log-Gamma doesn't look very symmetric which is why I didn't try to use the variance of the distribution since it isn't as meaningful as it is in a gaussian.

Comment: If we use a known distribution like the log-Gamma we can use `ppf`. The percent point function (which is the inverse of CDF). If we used the Empirical CDF we would have to invert it but you don't seem to have to do that here as you are happy with the log-Gamma.

Comment: Please add this new information as an edit to the post. Not everybody reads comments!

Comment: So is your X about how to visualize a large network?

Comment: Although you are not responsible for naming this distribution, note that it confusingly uses the *opposite* of the convention that brings us (among other things) the well-known lognormal distribution.  According to this convention, your variable has an "exp-Gamma" distribution because its exponential has a Gamma distribution.